# Que indices implementar para mejorar rendimiento en una tabla MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, rendimiento, indices

Buen día.

Estoy presentado problemas con la ejecución de querys en una talba MySQL, las consultas suelen demorar bastante tiempo, por lo que veo necesario la implementación de índices apropiados para esta tabla, la cual cuenta con la siguiente descripción:

```
Table: CONSULTA
Columns:
CODIGO varchar(38) PK 
USUARIO varchar(20) 
DIRECCION_IP varchar(20) 
FECHA_INICIAL datetime(6) 
CODIGO_RESPUESTA varchar(5) 
OBSERVACION varchar(255) 
DATOS_ENVIADOS varchar(255) 
DATOS_RESPUESTA json 
HASH varchar(255) 
TIPO_CONSULTA varchar(120) 
FECHA_FINAL datetime(6) 
ES_CACHEADA int 
ID_TRANSACCION varchar(255)
```

---

```
    CREATE TABLE `CONSULTA` (
  `CODIGO` varchar(38) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `USUARIO` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `DIRECCION_IP` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `FECHA_INICIAL` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `CODIGO_RESPUESTA` varchar(5) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `OBSERVACION` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `DATOS_ENVIADOS` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `DATOS_RESPUESTA` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `HASH` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIPO_CONSULTA` varchar(120) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,
  `FECHA_FINAL` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `ES_CACHEADA` int NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `ID_TRANSACCION` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CODIGO`),
  KEY `USUARIO` (`USUARIO`,`CODIGO_RESPUESTA`,`FECHA_INICIAL`,`CODIGO`),
  KEY `CODIGO_RESPUESTA` (`CODIGO_RESPUESTA`,`TIPO_CONSULTA`,`DATOS_ENVIADOS`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin;
```

En esta tabla se almacena mucha información que comprende los movimientos de todo un mes, la consulta que utilizo y que es la que demora mucho tiempo en traer resultados es la siguiente:

```
   SELECT 
 CODIGO,USUARIO, FECHA_INICIAL,DATOS_ENVIADOS,CODIGO_RESPUESTA,OBSERVACION,TIPO_CONSULTA,ID_TRANSACCION 
FROM CONSULTA 
where 
USUARIO NOT IN ('USUARIO1','USUARIO2','USUARIO3')
and FECHA_INICIAL BETWEEN '2022-06-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-07-01 00:00:00'
ORDER BY FECHA_INICIAL asc;
```

Agradezco que me puedan indicar cuales y como implementar indices para mejorar el rendimiento de esta tabla.

Comment: Veo no tienes relaciones con ninguna otra tabla, pudieras implementar índices sobre las columnas fecha_inicial y usuario.

Comment: Así es @Francisco es una tabla que funciona a modo de bitácora, sabes que índices podría utilizar?